# How to consume a SOAP WebService with AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, soap, wsdl

Well, I have a SOAP WebService that is consumed usually for a PHP client, working perfectly ... by ajax consumption this php and populate my template ..

My current application does the following process `Angular <-> PHP <-> service.wsdl`

I discovered the possibility of excluding this PHP bridge, directly consuming SOAP WebService, using [angular-soap](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap) .

But when playing the example, I can not return any information .. or error.

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="public/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/soapclient.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/angular.soap.js"></script>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoap'])

            .factory("testService", ['$soap',function($soap){
                var base_url = "http://localhost/api/1/service.wsdl";

                return {
                    getEmpresa: function(){
                        var x =  $soap.post(base_url,"getEmpresas");
                        return x;
                    }
                }
            }])

            .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testService) {

              testService.getEmpresa().then(function(response){
                $scope.response = response;
              });

            })
        </script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        {{response}}
    </body>
</html>
```

service wsdl

```
<!--  WSDL file generated by Zend Studio.  -->
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Service" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Service" targetNamespace="urn:Service">
    <message name="getEmpresas">
        <part name="getEmpresas" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getEmpresasResponse">
        <part name="getEmpresasReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="HomePortType">
        <operation name="getEmpresas">
            <input message="typens:getEmpresas"/>
            <output message="typens:getEmpresasResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="HomeBinding" type="typens:HomePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="getEmpresas">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:HomeAction"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Service" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Service" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="ServiceService">
        <port name="HomePort" binding="typens:HomeBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/app/homeCrtl.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

When you make the request it sends an envelope via Request Payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
          <getEmpresas xmlns="urn:Service"></getEmpresas>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

the browser tool for `network > Response` he returns my own wsdl described above ..

you need / have to change something on the server?

thank you

Comment: Sure seems like it would cleaner in the long run to use json between your php and angular client