# Error Calling a WSDL service from angularjs using soapclient.js and angular.soap.js

Tags: angularjs, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to call wsdl service (created by dataflux data management studio )from my angular application.

I had already referred to the post 
1) [AngularJS - SOAP Service Integration With AngularJS Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490483/angularjs-soap-service-integration-with-angularjs-model)
2) [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example)
3) [How to consume a SOAP WebService with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613323/how-to-consume-a-soap-webservice-with-angularjs)

I am using soapclient.js and angular.soap.js

It is giving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null
soapCallback @ angular.soap.js:16
SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest @ soapclient.js:214
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange @ soapclient.js:187
```

My code in controller:

`$scope.getData = function(){

        soapService.DMService().then(function(response){
             $scope.response = response;
        });
     }`

In app.js,

```
 app.factory("soapService", ['$soap',function($soap){
   var base_url =              "http://myserver:9000/WSDL_Web_Service/service__DashBoard.WSDL";

    return {
        DMService: function(){          
            return $soap.post(base_url,"procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf");
        }
    }
    }]);
```

My wsdl service : service__Dashboard.WSDL

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <definitions name="DMService"
            targetNamespace="http://archserver.wsdl.dataflux.com"
            xmlns:tns="http://archserver.wsdl.dataflux.com"
            xmlns:archxsd="archserver.xsd.dataflux.com"

     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:MIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
     xmlns:DIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/"
     xmlns:WSDL="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <types>
     <schema
            targetNamespace="archserver.xsd.dataflux.com"
            xmlns:tns="archserver.xsd.dataflux.com"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="unqualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

      <complexType name="request">
        <sequence>
       </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in" type="tns:request"/>

      <complexType name="response">
        <sequence>
        <element name="result" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_out" type="tns:response"/>

     </schema>
    </types>


    <message name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in">
     <part name="body" element="archxsd:procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in"/>
    </message>
    <message name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_out">
     <part name="body" element="archxsd:procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_out"/>
    </message>


    <portType name="DataManagementServicePortType">
     <operation name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in">
      <documentation></documentation>
      <input message="tns:procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in"/>
      <output message="tns:procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_out"/>
     </operation>
    </portType>


    <binding name="DataManagementService" type="tns:DataManagementServicePortType">
     <SOAP:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
     <operation name="procsvc_service__DashBoard.djf_in">
      <SOAP:operation soapAction="service__DashBoard.djf*1*57195B25CE0B6D37"/>
      <input>
       <SOAP:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
       <SOAP:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
     </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="DMService">
     <documentation>Data Management Server</documentation>
     <port name="DMService" binding="tns:DataManagementService">
      <SOAP:address location="http://someserver:21000"/>
     </port>
    </service>
    </definitions>   `
```

changes in soapclient.js (in method SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest on line 201 ):

```
var nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, method + **"_in"**);
    if(nd.length == 0)
        nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, "return");
```

I feel, I might be calling the wsdl method in wrong way, but not able to figure out how it should be. If anybody can throw more light on how it should be done...it would be great

Thanks...